# Does this function already exist? (Maybe monad)

Tags: haskell, monads

I find myself writing this:

```
and_then :: x -> Maybe [x] -> Maybe [x]
x `and_then` mxs = do
  xs <- mxs
  return (x:xs)
```

Is there some simpler way to achieve the same thing?

Basically this is your standard recursive loop that processes a list - except that processing can fail (which is different from the result merely being an empty list). That means that where I would normally write

```
z : process xs ys
```

I now have to write

```
z `and_then` process xs ys
```

Since this is a rather common idiom, I was wondering whether some pre-existing function could help me out. (Several Hoogle searches fail to find any functions with types similar to the above.)

Comment: How about `fmap (x:) mxs`?

Comment: Of course, Hoogle will only tell you if *one function* has the type you want. It can't tell you if a *combination* of library functions will do the job... It sounds tempting to suggest this as a new feature, but I fear there would be no way to tell exactly what code the user wanted half the time...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since your `do` notation is only invoking the `Maybe` layer we might think about the `(:)` operation as being independent of the `Maybe`'s effect—it's just yet another function being passed to the value wrapped in `Maybe`. That leads us to generalize the code a bit

```
foo :: (x -> b -> b) -> x -> Maybe b -> Maybe b
foo f x m = do
  b <- m
  return (f x b)
```

This makes it much more clear that we're just dealing with an `fmap`

```
fmap fx m = do b <- m
               return (fx b)
```

So perhaps the most standard way of writing your desired function is

```
(z:) <$> process xs ys
```